# RSA Key-exchange iOS to Java

Tags: java, ios, certificate, rsa, exchange-server

on my iPhone Application I generated a public-private keypair using **SecKeyGeneratePair**.

Now I want to send the Public Key to my Java server. Is there a possibility to extract modulus and exponent or to generate an X509 certificate from my public key, so that i can use it on my java server?

Comment: did you ever get answer to this question?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could generate an X509 Certificate from the public key and use it from your java server. read this article, its quite helpful: http://www.mayrhofer.eu.org/create-x509-certs-in-java/

Comment: Thanks for your help, but generating the x509 certificate on the Java side is not a problem. My problem is to generate the certificate on the client side (iPhone)